# How to click a Button that only becomes visible on MouseHover over a Composite using SWTBot

Tags: java, swt, swtbot

I have to use a relatively unknown SWT-Framwork called Riena. This has an ImageButton that is composed of a `Composite` and a `Button(SWT_PUSH)`. This Button is invisible by default and becomes visible if you hover over the Composite with your mouse.

I want to click that button with SWTBot. How can I do that? SWTBot doesn't find the id of the Button. I think this is due to the invisible-state.

So I think that I need to hover over the Button or Composite. How can I do this, if it is possible?

Comment: Did you make sure that it is caused by the invisible state of the button? i.e. did you make it visible by default and see if swtbot can find it?

Comment: I cannot change that behavior without recompiling the riena-framework since that ImageButton is part of that framework. When I try to set the State manually from outside, the state is overidden, because the Button changes that visibility-state in numerous events. So this is currently just a theory... but I'm quite shure that this is the reason.

Comment: I was able to validate the theory the other way round: If I take another Widget wich is visible by default and set the visibility to false I get the same error. It cannot be selected anymore...